# Can robin eggs still hatch after two weeks, with quite some time unattended?

Tags: robins

A while ago, a robin built a nest under the shelter of my house door. Probably more than two weeks ago, it laid eggs and incubated them for a few days. Last week there was heavy rain. The robin flew away and was never seen again. That is, the eggs were left unattended from then on.

Can the eggs still hatch, incubated naturally or artificially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robin eggs usually hatch [13-14 days after laying](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/wildlife-guides/bird-a-z/robin/nesting-and-breeding-habits/).  So, it looks bad for your nest.

If you were lucky and you get some chicks, they will need to be kept warm for at least another 10 days while their feathers grow. At 14 days, they will be ready to leave the nest.  However, they are still dependent upon their parents for little while longer.

You would also, of course, have to feed them during this time.

Robins do abandon a nest if they feel it has been compromised.  However, they will very often build another and lay another clutch.  So, your mother bird may be happily raising chicks somewhere else.